# how can I develop a timeline like Slider Revolution's and like that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, timeline, vis.js-timeline

I want to develop a timeline like Slider Revolutions. for controlling objects sequentially over time. Every object has its own row in the timeline and will move while the player's vertical scroll is moving over its horizontal bar.

- What is the best technology? (something like Reactjs or vis.js, etc.)
- Do you know any sample code to facilitate the development process?

you can watch the playing live process through these links:
https://www.sliderrevolution.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/timelineplay.mp4
https://daybrush.com/scenejs/features.html#timeline

[image: a screenshot of timeline]